# Sonar GitLab authentication

Tags: oauth, gitlab, sonarqube

SonarQube ID information
Server ID: 243B8A4D-AXy4FBPDTMflcG_rMCZY
Version: 9.1.0.47736
Date: 2021-10-27
and GitLab 13.0.0
and while I try to connect to SonarQube using GitLab credentials I get
The redirect URI included is not valid.

log from web process is

```
2021.10.27 10:05:31 WARN  web[AXy4FINzHISAffoAAAY/][o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] Fail to callback authentication with 'gitlab'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode null object
    at com.github.scribejava.core.utils.Preconditions.check(Preconditions.java:49)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.utils.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:19)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.utils.OAuthEncoder.encode(OAuthEncoder.java:26)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.Parameter.asUrlEncodedPair(Parameter.java:16)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.ParameterList.asFormUrlEncodedString(ParameterList.java:63)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.getByteArrayPayload(OAuthRequest.java:363)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuthService.execute(OAuthService.java:115)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.sendAccessTokenRequestSync(OAuth20Service.java:46)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.getAccessToken(OAuth20Service.java:97)
    at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.getAccessToken(OAuth20Service.java:92)
    at org.sonar.auth.gitlab.GitLabIdentityProvider.onCallback(GitLabIdentityProvider.java:115)
    at org.sonar.auth.gitlab.GitLabIdentityProvider.callback(GitLabIdentityProvider.java:102)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.handleOAuth2Provider(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:92)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.handleProvider(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:75)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.doFilter(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:68)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
    at org.sonar.server.authentication.DefaultAdminCredentialsVerifierFilter.doFilter(DefaultAdminCredentialsVerifierFilter.java:89)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginsRiskConsentFilter.doFilter(PluginsRiskConsentFilter.java:77)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:108)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:68)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:76)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:57)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:66)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1651)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```